# Python syntax number + array

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

I occasionally meet this python construction: number + array
And I wonder what is the return value, is it number or array. What it does?

Example, where I met it is this:

```
 def __init__(self, n):      
  self.wins = np.zeros( n )
  self.trials = np.zeros(n )

 def sample( self, n=1 ):   
 for k in range(n):        
    choice = np.argmax( rbeta( 1 + self.wins, 1 + self.trials - self.wins) )        
    choices[ k ] = choice
return
```

Note: I know almost nothing about Python

Comment: Where are you seeing a "number plus array" in there? I can see `1 + ...`

Comment: @doctorlove, `1 + self.wins`

Comment: So you are asking what 1 + a numpy array means? Add the scalar 1 to everything in the array - this is numpy *not* neat python.

Comment: `I don't know almost nothing about Python`, that double negative

Comment: google "numpy broadcasting"

Comment: @JoeC ok it is true I know nothing about Python...I was just curious about the structure of other languages...

Comment: @Babu not that, i was just saying double negative makes a positive, so by saying ` I don't know almost nothing about Python`, its like saying you know python. It's a joke -_-||

Comment: Ah...I see now :D ...I will edit it ... and after you read this I can remove this comments, because this has nothing to do with the question

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not about the syntax per se (addition is nothing special syntax-wise), but about addition methods of `numpy` arrays. For the `numpy` array objects, addition of scalars is implemented so that the result is an array where all elements are added the scalar.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(0, 5)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [4]: 1+a
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Suggested reading:

- [Python Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), specifically the part about [`object.__add__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and [`object.__radd__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__);
- [Tentative NumPy tutorial.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

this isn't number + array

it is scalar + nparray.

it adds the scalar to each element of the np array